# Can't detect camera with gphoto2 in Ubuntu(VM)

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, libgphoto2

I'm trying to control my EOS 1000D with gphoto2.
But can't detect with gphoto2 it.
[image]

with lsusb I can find the Camera.
[image]

Any idea what is going wrong?

My setup:
VirtualBox Version 5.2.18 r124319 (Qt5.6.2), Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS,
gphoto2 2.5.15, libgphoto2 2.5.17, libgphoto2_port 0.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

+ compiling, install libgphoto and gphoto2 by hand did the trick.

For some reason libgphoto2_port 0.12.0 did not suport USB  (you can check with`gphoto --version`). It require libusb ([see here](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-libgphoto2_port.html)) . libusb-1.0-0 was installed. Looks like you need libusb-1.0-0-dev to run it proper.